# Some better Loop exiter than feof()

Tags: c, file, character

I really have a problem in here. It seems that i dont really find the best way to exit a loop when reading characters from a file. I know that every tutorial suggests that i shouldn't use while( !feof() ) but they dont really suggest anything else than putting fgets() in the while and that is not really apropriate because i want to read the whole FILE content in my variable.

```
while (!feof(newFile))
    {
        newString[i++] = fgetc(newFile);
    }
    newString[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;

//this is the resoult seen with the debugger
newFile content = ABC
newString[0] = 65 (A)
newString[1] = 66 (B)
newString[2] = 67 (C)
newString[3] = 10 (\n)
newString[4] = -1
newString[5] = 0 (\0)
```

I am looking for a solution and some advices about how to improve my algorithm.

Comment: if you need the whole file in a char buffer, have a look at mmap

Comment: `feof` only returns true *after* you try to read past EOF - so by the time your while loop stops, you've already read the EOF marker into your array. When you hit the end of the file, `fgetc` returns `EOF` (which is an actual constant), so check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int c;

while ((c = fgetc(newFile)) != EOF) newString[i++] = c;
newString[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I am at entry level in C programming but i seem to realize that there are some simple basic algorithms that i have to just dream about them. There seems to just be a way things should be done. The question is, can any1 point me to some website or something where i can found all basic algorithms or things like that?

Comment: @sorin.va you have to fiddle around a bit on the net and make some research effort yourself. BTW this code is good only as long as `newString` is large enough (id est, you still have to somehow determine the buffer size beforehand).

Comment: maybe that's just me, but I don't consider side-effects in conditionals "beautiful"...

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin, true, `while ((c = fgetc(newFile)) != EOF) newString[i++] = c;` seems a better approach

Comment: `while ((newString[i++] = fgetc(newFile)) != EOF);` I suspect is wrong.  E.g. Assume EOF = -1 and newString is a `(signed) char[]`.  Should `fgetc(newFile)` return 255, 255 will be assigned to `newString[i++]` as a `char` as `(char) 255 --> -1`.  The `char` gets converted to an `int` for compare to EOF and compares equally although the EOF was not returned by `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 1):

For reading whole test files into memory, I suggest using mmap. This has the benefit, that all buffering and reading can be handled by your operating system, and you can focus your code on the task at hand. (also, it's usually faster than buffering stuff yourself.)

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int 
main (void)
{
  int fd = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd == -1)
    return 0; // file open failed

  struct stat sb;
  int res = fstat(fd, &sb);
  if (res == -1)
    return 0; // stat failed

  size_t length = sb.st_size;

  char *data = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (!data)
    return 0; // mmap failed

  // iterate over characters
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    printf("'%c'\n", data[i]);

  munmap(data, length);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact is that i am preparing an exam and only available libries are cstdio/cstdlib/cstring

Comment: @sorin.va 1.) cstdio, cstdlib, cstring are c++ headers, not c headers.  2.) homework/exam prep questions should be marked as such, and include a list of limitations.

Answer (score 0):

> they dont really suggest anything else than putting fgets() in the while and that is not really apropriate

That is absolutely, entirely appropriate. `fgets()` reads the file line by line, and you can append each line onto then end of a dybamically expanding buffer.

However, if you don't want to use `fgets()`, and you just want to read the file at once: use `fread()`.

```
FILE *f = fopen("foo.txt", "rb");
if (!f)
    abort(); // "handle" error

fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t len = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *buf = malloc(len + 1);
if (!buf)
    abort();

if (fread(buf, len, 1, f) != 1) {
    // handle reading error
}

buf[len] = 0;
fclose(f);
```